# How to use a list of filenames with spaces in a variable to pass the contents of the variable as an argument to du?

Tags: bash, filenames, space, du

I have a list of filenames in variable in my bash script.
And I need to summarize disk usage of listed files.
But I can't figure out how to escape spaces in file names.
I tried various options, none of them worked.

It is a my test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_LIST="/tmp/filename_without_spaces
           /tmp/filename\ with\ spaces"

du -shc $FILE_LIST

FILE_LIST="/tmp/filename_without_spaces
           /tmp/filename\\ with\\ spaces"

du -shc $FILE_LIST

FILE_LIST="/tmp/filename_without_spaces
           \"/tmp/filename with spaces\""

du -shc $FILE_LIST
```

and the script output I got:

```
1,0G    /tmp/filename_without_spaces
du: cannot access '/tmp/filename\': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'with\': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'spaces': No such file or directory
1,0G    total
1,0G    /tmp/filename_without_spaces
du: cannot access '/tmp/filename\': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'with\': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'spaces': No such file or directory
1,0G    total
1,0G    /tmp/filename_without_spaces
du: cannot access '"/tmp/filename': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'with': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'spaces"': No such file or directory
1,0G    total
```

The file with spaces in name could not be processed by du.

Comment: Variables hold data, not shell syntax (except spaces and wildcards); quotes and escapes are shell syntax, so putting them in variables doesn't do anything useful. See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bash arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_list=( /tmp/filename_without_spaces '/tmp/filename with spaces' )    
du -shc "${file_list[@]}"
```

---

An array maps numbers to strings. Bash >= 4 also has associative arrays (maps strings to strings).
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Arrays
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays

Answer (score 0):

#### Simpler Way

Use `find` and forget about spaces.

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec du -sh {} \;
```

These means:

- find only folders.
- only 1 depth folders. (no deeper sub folders; no current folder `.`)
- check their `du -sh` respectively.

---

#### Additional Notes:

```
# man du

du <options ... skipped> [file ...]
#                        ^^^^^^^^^^
#                        this means that you can pass several files as input.
```

And those inputs are separated by   (`space`)

So, given a `FILE_LIST` variable:

```
FILE_LIST="/tmp/filename_without_spaces
           /tmp/filename\ with\ spaces"
```

would be like pass input with

```
# case 1: bash
# 4 inputs

/tmp/filename_without_spaces  /tmp/filename\  with\  spaces
#                           ^^              ^^     ^^
#                     4 inputs seperated by these 3 spaces


# case 2: zsh
# 1 inputs, literally this

"/tmp/filename_without_spaces
           /tmp/filename\ with\ spaces"
```

None of them is what you want.

You need to give those inputs with their own double quotes (`"`).

Like an Array mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.
Spend some time reading over the [BashFAQs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), such as [20](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) and [50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

If you have your filenames listed in a file, load them to an array.

```
$: cat file
file_one
file two
$: mapfile -t lst < file
$: du "${lst[@]}"
0       file_one
0       file two
```

If you are generating them dynamically and storing that output in `FILE_LIST`, how are you generating them? You might be able to just skip that step.

```
FILE_LIST="$(printf "%s\n" file????)" # don't do this
lst=( file???? )                      # use an array
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${lst[@]}"
[file two]
[file_one]
$: du "${lst[@]}"
0       file two
0       file_one
```

or just skip storing it and pass the globs straight to `du`

```
$: du file????
0       file two
0       file_one
```

`find` can use globs in the `-name` option too.

```
$: find /tmp/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'file????' -exec du {} +
0       /tmp/file two
0       /tmp/file_one
```